# Call member function when class type is not known

Tags: c++, boost, callback, pointer-to-member

I want to have a class that can have a callback set to a pointer to member function. This means I need to store the address of the function, and the address of the object instance. The function should have the proper prototype and return value to what the callback expects.

I've played around with `std::mem_fn` and `boost::bind` (with the Boost Signals2 library), but it seems like I have to know the type of the class containing the callback function to store this information.

It seems like there should be a way to store a couple `void*` that would point to any object/function, but this obviously smells funny, loses type safety, etc.

Given a class `SomeClass` with a method `some_method`, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
SomeClass obj;
some_other_class.set_callback(&SomeClass::some_method, &obj);
```

Here is how I was able to accomplish this using Boost. Note that this uses Boost signals, and seems like overkill for a simple callback. Also, there is the issue of signals using "combiners" to determine the return value of the callback, since there are potentially multiple slots connected to a single signal. I only need support for a single callback. Also note that this is a complete compilable program:

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct MessageSource
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void(const string &)> send_message;
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void(const string &)>::slot_type slot_type;

    template<typename A, typename B>
    boost::signals2::connection connect(A a, B b)
    {
        return send_message.connect(boost::bind(a, b, _1));
    }

    void send_msg(const string& msg)
    {
        send_message(msg);
    }
};

struct Printer
{
    void print(const string& msg) { std::cout << msg << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    {
        Printer p;
        MessageSource s;
        s.connect(&Printer::print, &p);
        s.send_msg("test");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think the magic here is the fact that `boost::bind()` is able to handle a variety of types for its first argument. I just don't get how it can hold onto it in a private field of some sort without knowing the type...

Is this a case where a functor is really the right solution? It seems like member functions are so much more convenient to use...

Comment: If you have access to C++11 you could use `std::function<void(const std::string &)>` and `[p] (const std::string & m) { p.print(m); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by cdhowie above, I was able to come up with the following solution using `std::function` and `std::bind`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct MessageSource
{
    function<void(const string& msg)> _callback;

    template<typename A, typename B>
    void connect(A func_ptr, B obj_ptr)
    {
        _callback = bind(func_ptr, obj_ptr, placeholders::_1);
    }

    void send_msg(const string& msg)
    {
        if (_callback)
            _callback(msg);
    }

    void disconnect()
    {
        _callback = nullptr;
    }
};

struct Printer
{
    void print(const string& msg) { std::cout << msg << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    {
        Printer p;
        MessageSource s;
        s.connect(&Printer::print, &p);
        s.send_msg("test");
        s.disconnect();
        s.send_msg("test again");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```